# add a custom uiview with xib in my storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview

I am using swift2.0 and I have just added a custom `UIView` called SortableTableTitleView:

[image]

[image]

and then I drag a `UIView` in my storyboard, and I changed the class of the view to SortableTableTitleView

[image]

When I tried to set the text of the label in the custom view, I just got a bad access error.

I tried to write the `initwithcoder` method of the view, but I don't know how I can load the element from xib. (It is somehow different with ObjectiveC). So, how can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `xib` files within the `Storboard` file. So either create the view fully in the `Storyboard` and use it as per normal. Or, add the view from your `xib` file add a `subView` to the view on the `storyboard` via code.

So something like this in the `viewController`:

```
UINib *nibFile = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SortableTableTitleView" bundle:nil];
            NSArray *views = [nibFile instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
            UIView *sortableTableTitleView = views[0]; //Assuming it is the only view in the xib file

//Add it where you want as a normal view now: 
[self.view addSubview: sortableTableTitleView];
```

I realise the code above is in objective-c - I'll get the Swift comparison when I get a gap (Being new to Swift and all)